# Create a new column based on two existing columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

This should a very simple task, surprisingly, I am unable to find any pointers either through search or through Excel documentation. 
I have two Column in my excel spreadsheet:

```
A  A111  A222  B  B111  B222  C
2    11   22   3   111   222  -
5    11   22   7   111   222  -
1    11   22   5   111   222  -
```

I want to create a third column C, which is the sum of the elements in the column A and column B as shown below:

```
C
5
12
6
```

How do I do it in one shot so I generate an entire column ?

Comment: Should the value in C (second row) be 12?

Comment: Sorry but I don't think you've explained it well enough. If you want column C to be A+B, what's the problem with a formula (in R1C1 format as it is easier to understand): =RC1+RC4   Then copy/paste that down the rows. Make the whole table into a list and new rows added will inherit the same formula. Not quite 1 step but close.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the ASCII code and then convert it to a character.

```
=Char(CODE(A1)+CODE(B1)-96)
```

The minus 96 will subtract the characters before the "a".

Comment: I don't think he is trying to add non-numeric characters.  Although this would work with letters the result of A+B=D

Comment: In his post it states A B with a result of C.  The char allows letters and numbers.